# Help with proving a function limit $\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}\frac{x^2 - 3}{2x^2+2x-1} = -\frac{2}{3}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, proof-writing, solution-verification

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}\frac{x^2 - 3}{2x^2+2x-1} = -\frac{2}{3}$$
Prove the limit by definition:
$$|\frac{x^2-3}{2x^2+2x-1}+\frac{2}{3}| < \epsilon \iff |\frac{(x -1+1)^2-3}{2(x-1+1)^2+2(x-1+1)-1}| +\frac{2}{3} <\epsilon \iff \\ \iff |\frac{(x - 1)^2+1 +2(x-1)-3}{2(x-1)^2+ 2 +4(x-1)+2(x-1)+1}| < \epsilon -\frac{2}{3}$$

Now I somehow want to say that $|x-1| < \delta$ by subtituting delta into the equation and saying that its less than or equal to later on. But I don't know how the inequalities work for the denominator, if I can do that.

Comment: I think it will be lot easier to calculate the limits of the numerator and denominator separately using $\epsilon-\delta$ and then put them together.